# Optimizing Quicksort in JAVA (checking earlier if sorted)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I want to check the array if it's sorted or not, before sorting the array with quicksort.
I'm always getting a stackoverflow in line 77, or an array index out of bounds error in line 65.
My basic idea was to check the first two numbers if they are sorted, then second and third, and so on. If they are not sorted, the whole while loop should cancel and start sorting with quicksort using the last correct sorted value as comperative value.

```
public class customQuickSort 
{
    Runtime runtime = new Runtime();

    private int[] a;
    private int n;
    boolean isSorted = true;
    int arraySortCount = 0;
    int x = 0;

    public customQuickSort(int[] unsorted)
    {
        sort(unsorted);
    }
    @Override
    public void sort(int[] a)
    {
        this.a=a;
        n=a.length;
        runtime.start();
        quicksort(0, n-1);
        runtime.end(getCounter());
    }

    private void quicksort (int lo, int hi)
    {
        int i=lo, j=hi;
        while(isSorted = true && arraySortCount < a.length-1)
        {
            if(a[arraySortCount] <= a[(arraySortCount+1)])
            {
                if(arraySortCount == a.length-2)
                {
                    System.out.println("array sorted ascending");
                }
            }
            else if(a[arraySortCount] >= a[(arraySortCount+1)])
            {
                if(arraySortCount == a.length-2)
                {
                    System.out.println("array sorted descending");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isSorted = false;
                x=a[c(arraySortCount)];
                System.out.println("unsorted");
            }
            arraySortCount++;
        }
        if(isSorted == false)
        {

            while (i<=j)
            {    
                while (a[i]<x)
                {
                    i++; 
                }
                while (a[j]>x) 
                {
                    j--; 
                }
                if (i<=j)
                {
                    exchange(i, j);
                    i++; j--;
                }
            }

            if (lo<j) quicksort(lo, j);
            if (i<hi) quicksort(i, hi);
        }
    }

    private void exchange(int i, int j)
    {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line 65? What is line 77?

Comment: Are you getting a stackoverflow in java?

Comment: line 65 is while (a[j]>x)
line 77 is if (i<hi) quicksort(i, hi);
yes, i'm getting a stackoverflow in java

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T> c)
```

it uses a highly optimized sorting algorithm

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
>   iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
>   when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
>   performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
>   randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the
>   implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage
>   requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays
>   to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending
>   order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and
>   descending order in different parts of the the same input array. It is
>   well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate
>   the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
>   ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting
>   and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth
>   Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January
>   1993.

[read more here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: But probably this is homework or something and he needs to do this by hand.

Comment: yeah, it's a sort of homework where we have to understand how to optimize on our own algorithms, so this does not help me :(

Comment: Alright fair enough :) But next time please state the exact requirements, makes it easier to answer.